# Проблема с форматом даты при использовании tag-хелперов в ASP.NET Core 2 VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .netcore2.0

Добрый день.

Есть код для ввода параметров фильтрации (делал согласно [статье](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/12.9.php)). Всё прекрасно работало пока не столкнулся с необходимостью делать фильтрацию по временному интервалу.

```
<form id=SearchFull method="get" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datestartpicker'>
        <input name="DateStartInput" asp-for="FilterViewModel.SelectedDateStart" type='text' class="form-control" />
        @*@Html.TextBox("DateStartInput", Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateStart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datefinishpicker'>
        <input name="DateFinishInput" asp-for="FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish" type='text' class="form-control" />
        @*@Html.TextBox("DateFinishInput", Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Фильтр" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

При использовании кода для начальной даты:

```
@Html.TextBox("DateStartInput", Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateStart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

и соответственно для конечной даты:

```
@Html.TextBox("DateFinishInput", Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Фильтрует без проблем.

При использовании кода:

```
<input name="DateFinishInput" asp-for="FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish" type='text' class="form-control" />
```

**Меняются местами день и месяц!** В контроллер приходит уже измененная дата. Соответственно фильтрует не правильно. При повторном нажатии на "Фильтр" опять меняет местами день и месяц. В контроллер приходит уже правильная дата. 
Можно было бы оставить рабочий вариант, но у меня далее на странице происходит сортировка и пагинация, всё с помощью tag-хелперов. Соответственно при переходе на следующую страницу или сортировке происходит смена дня и месяца. Подскажите куда копать, что посмотреть. Я новичок в ASP.NET, подробности приветствуются.

P.S. Уточнение в процессе обсуждения. При передаче параметров методом Post -работает, а методом Get - как было указано в статье - нет. И непонятно было как эту проблему решать в конструкциях типа `<a asp-action...>`  ...

Comment: День и месяц могут меняться если на сервере или клиенте выставлены параметры форматирования даты с указанием месяца перед указанием дня. Панель управления - региональные настройки - настройки даты и времени

Comment: Добрый день, tym32167! Это я проверил в первую очередь, видел похожий пост, с Вашим ответом, но комментировать пока не могу (репутации нет) Формат даты в региональных настройках dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: ...сначала день, потом месяц. Попробовал так же тестовый сайт на рабочем сервере развернуть, проблема осталась. Если мне нужно добавить дату в БД, то добавляет правильно, и отображает из базы так же верно. Может есть какие-то ещё языковые настройки в студии? Что ещё проверить можно?

Comment: Попробовал, ради эксперимента, выставить на локальном (рабочем с VS) компьютере формат данных "MM.dd.yyyy", запустил проект и, вуаля, во время фильтрации дата остается правильной. Опубликовал на сервере (там дата в формате dd.MM.yyyy) - месяц и день опять поменялись местами...

Comment: Я с вебом года 2 не работал, но там вроде есть тег для форматирования типа ```asp-format``` - вы его пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал. `<input name="DateFinishInput" asp-for="FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish" asp-format="{0:MM.dd.yyyy}" type='text' class="form-control" />`, теперь фильтрация работает правильно.

Comment: Обязательно ли указывать ```type='text'``` ?

Comment: Но что мне делать с сортировкой, фильтрация при сортировке тоже должна сохраниться. `<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@(Model.SortViewModel.Sort1)" asp-route-MedInstInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedMedInst)" asp-route-CompanyInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedCompany)"  asp-route-DateStartInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateStart)" asp-route-DateFinishInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish)" >Нас. пункт</a></h4>` В такую конструкцию пока не понял куда asp-format можно/нужно ставить...

Comment: `asp-route-DateStartInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDa‌​teStart)" asp-route-DateFinishInput="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedD‌​ateFinish)"` и число и месяц опять меняются местами. type='text' использовать обязательно для этого дататаймпикера: [ссылка](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), но я пробовал его отключать, проблема оставалась.

Comment: К сожалению на эти вопросы ответить не могу - ждем кого-нибудь сведущего

Comment: Получилось ли найти решение вашей проблемы?

Comment: Пока нет. После внимательного изучения, варианты с форматированием и без tag-хелперов оказались тоже ошибочные, в контроллере я вижу всегда перевёрнутую дату. Решил отложить поиск решения, с понедельника/вторника снова начну.

Comment: В вопросе не сказано, какая локаль у вас выставлена на клиентской машине, и как именно прикручен datepicker, так что придется гадать. Попробуйте локализовать проблему - уберите дейтпикер с поля, оставьте поле чисто текстовым, и проверьте, будет ли разворачиватся значение. Допишите в вопрос: 1. культуру браузера. 2. результат вызова Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDa‌​‌​teStart.ToString() при первом запросе. 3. Скрин с датой в textbox фильтра. 4. скрин с датой.ToString() в контроллере при повторном запросе. Все три должны совпадать.

Comment: Если не совпадает - значит формат ломается именно в том месте, где наблюдается расхождение. Если совпадает, но после возвращения datepicker перестает совпадать - значит у вашего скриптового datepicker-а формат даты отличается от формата в .net. Т.е. разворот даты происходит именно в момент инициализации дейтпикера. Вобщем, локализуйте проблему. Потому что в текущем виде она не воспроизводится на основании кода в вопросе.

Comment: Скорее всего ваш дейтпикер работает с локалью по умолчанию (us?), которая не совпадает с локалью, обнаруженной asp.net, и вы получаете примерно следующий эффект - https://jsfiddle.net/srd4gv73/1/ - обратите внимание, как Bootstrap Datepicker превращает 1-е февраля в 2-е января, полностью игнорируя различие в разделителях :)

Comment: пикер проверял, ставил  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({locale: 'ru'}); он ни при чем и уже отключен. на вьюшке осталось: `<input name="DateStartInput" asp-for="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateStart)" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <input name="DateFinishInput" asp-for="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDateFinish)" type="text" class="form-control" />` 1. культура браузеров ru у всех (хром, эксплорер, эйдж)

Comment: 2. Результат вызова - перевернутый. Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedDa‌​‌​teStart.ToString() - 03.01.2017 (если ввожу 01.03.2017) и далее по кругу - месяц и день меняются. 3.[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/aYw141Ch3Phc7P) 4.[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/gO5tI8ru3PhcET)

Comment: Вот более развернутый 4 пункт [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/Zl3IHFY53PhcgN)      далее в текстбоксе уже вижу:[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/kGtoArWj3PhcrH) ничего не меняя жму "фильтр" и в контроллере вижу: [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/uOR16Oai3PhdES) там в последнем скриншоте заменил тип контрольного значения с DateTime на string, но сути не меняет. Что так что эдак, где-то переворачивается дата :-(

Comment: Посмотрите  DateFinishInput в момент переворота. Там должно быть значение, отправленное из текстбокса. Если там значение неперевернутое, а в параметре контроллера в тот же момент - перевернутое, значит вы где-то намудрили с настройками локализации (т.к. через стандартный UseRequestLocalization все точно работает). Сделайте копию проекта, удалите из нее все лишнее, оставьте одну форму с текстбоксом и кнопкой + Action-ы для них на сервере. Приведите весь код проекта в вопросе, и продублируйте ссылкой на github, по возможности. Сейчас кода из вопроса недостаточно для воспроизведения проблемы :(

Comment: И да, тут для нотификаций нужно упоминать пользователя через @ (кроме автора поста) - иначе нотификации о комментариях не приходят.

Comment: Вот минимальный пример с датой - https://github.com/PashaPash/DateRoundtrip - на нем ничего местами не меняется. Сводите свой код к такому же размеру, пока проблема не локализуете

Comment: @PashaPash вот изменил минимальный пример[https://github.com/ASkrip78/SomeProblems.git](https://github.com/ASkrip78/SomeProblems.git). Старался сделать контроллер с параметрами как у меня, поэтому немного лишнего наворотил, но проблему частично удалось локализовать. Не совсем понятно куда дальше копать: согласно этой статье[https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/12.9.php](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/12.9.php) надо использовать именно метод "GET" который приводит к смене dd MM.

Comment: @PashaPash И потом, для сортировки и пагинации используется строка типа `<a asp-action="Index"
               asp-route-sortOrder="@(Model.SortViewModel.NameSort)"
               asp-route-name="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName)"
               asp-route-company="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedCompany)">Имя</a>` которая приводит к смене даты и месяца. Пока не ясно что тут менять `<form method="get">` или `<form method="post">` вообще отсутствуют, одни роутинги... Такое впечатление что глаз замылился и я простой вещи в упор не вижу? :-(((

Comment: @Андрей а, тогда вы напоролись на проблему типа "так задумано". сейчас оформлю ответом. Но вам стоит отредактировать вопрос, и сказать, что при передаче POST-ом работает, а GET-ом - нет.

Comment: А какое отношение к посту и гету имеет код `<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@(Model.SortViewModel.NameSort)" asp-route-name="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName)" asp-route-company="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedCompany)"‌​>Имя</a>`? Или что использовать вместо этой конструкции чтобы сохранять параметры фильтрации при сортировке?

Comment: @Андрей сейчас допишу полноценный ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC не всегда использует текущую культуру при парсинге значений, пришедших от клиента.

Контроллер может получать значение из трех различных источников:

- RouteData - данные роутинга
- URI query string - параметры, переданные в URL при GET-запросе
- Request form - данные, переданные внутри запроса при POST-запросе.

Текущая культура используется только при парсинге Request form. Значения из RouteData и query string всегда обрабатываются как строки в invariant culture.

Это сделано из соображений переносимости URL. Например, вы отправите URL с датами в фильтре знакомому, который сидит под английской локалью - он будет ожидать, что ссылка откроется корректно, и подхватит те же значения. Поэтому сервер парсит значения из query string без учета текущей культуры, в en-US, и разворачивает дату и месяц.

Возможных решений несколько:

Для форм:

- Использовать POST, а не GET. При этом параметры фильтрации не будут попадать в URL. Стоит использовать, если нет необходимости поддерживать прямые ссылки на URL фильтров.
- Использовать GET, но на стороне контроллера принимать `string`, а не `DateTime`. Преобразовывать `string` в `DateTime` в текущей локали. Такие ссылки можно будет добавить в закладки, но при смене локали они перестанут работать.
- Комбо: Использовать POST, но в ответ на него отдавать редирект на адрес с cultureinvariant параметрами в URL. Данные дойдут до сервера за счет POST, а сформированные при обработке POST ссылки будут всегда содержать данные в invariant culture и будут валидными на любой машине в качестве параметров при GET.

Для ссылок (`<a asp-action...`): явно вызывать `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` для параметров дат.

Похожий вопрос на enSO: [MVC DateTime binding with incorrect date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/528545/1988244).

Comment: Спасибо! Идея ясна, теперь все работает. В конце вопроса добавил комментарий про POST и GET, но для меня ключевым моментом стало использование `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` в ссылках типа `<a asp-action...`

Comment: Спасибо! Высылаю ваши законные бонусные баллы :)